# Swift Playground didn't recognize structs in other folders

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation, avaudioengine, playgrounds

I'm using AVAudioEngine of AVFoundation with SwiftUI in Swift Playground and using MVVM as Architecture. But if I separate my structs in files, I receive two errors: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT. and Cannot find file in scope. The only way that all works is using them in the same file.

Here is the playground base code, where I call MusicCreatorView.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

public struct StartView: View {

    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink("Start", destination: MusicCreatorView())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(StartView()) // error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
```

AudioEngine can be found by StartView (if called at StartView, just move SIGABRT error from PlaygroundPage.current.setLineView() to where it is called) but can't be found by MusicCreatorView.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

public struct AudioEngine {
    public var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    public var player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    public var audioBuffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer?
    public var audioFormat: AVAudioFormat?
    public var audioFile: AVAudioFile? {
        didSet {
            if let audioFile = audioFile {
                audioFormat = audioFile.fileFormat
            }
        }
    }
    public var audioFileURL: URL? {
        didSet {
            if let audioFileURL = audioFileURL {
                audioFile = try? AVAudioFile(forReading: audioFileURL)
            }
        }
    }

    public init() {
        setupAudio()
    }

    public mutating func setupAudio() {
        audioFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "EverybodysCirculation", withExtension: "mp3")
        guard let format = audioFormat else { return }
    
        engine.attach(player)
        engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: format)
        engine.prepare()
    
        do {
            try engine.start()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    public func scheduleAudioFile() {
        guard let audioFile = audioFile else { return }
    
        player.scheduleFile(audioFile, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)
    }

    public func playSound() {
        player.isPlaying ? player.pause() : player.play()
    }

}
```

Trying to call AudioEngine at MusicCreatorView

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

public struct MusicCreatorView: View {
    var audioEngine = AudioEngine() // Cannot find 'AudioEngine' in scope

    public init() {}

    public var body: some View {
        Text("Try to Create your own music")
        Button("play") {
            print("apertou")
            audioEngine.playSound() // audioEngine <<error type>>
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how my files are organized
https://i.stack.imgur.com/losWf.png

Answer (score 0):

Multiple files in Sources cannot see *each other*. They are just independent libraries available to the *actual playground*. You should be developing this in a real iOS project, rather than a playground.

Comment: So, there is no way to make a bridge or something like that to connect these files?

Comment: Yes they can see each other - you just need to declare the contents as public - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to explicitly declare stuff as public. Its annoying, and sometimes I need to close and reopen the playground for the scoping to take effect after marking them public.

Comment: Somehow this reads more like a comment, for which you have the privilege, than like [answer].